# Manually Inserting Joomla Show Cart NON sef URL

Tags: joomla1.5, virtuemart, joomla-sef-urls, sef

I have been having some SEF URL issues so I updated my Joomla SH404SEF module and I discussed my issues with a support guy from the company that supplies the 404SEF module and he realized that somebody had manually inserted an SEF URL for the Show Cart link, and that was messing up their module's URL conversion. So he asked me to disable the SEF module for now, and to MANUALLY insert the default NON SEF URL for the "Show Cart" link and I have no idea how to do that! He said that this NON SEF URL should be somewhere in my Virtuemart component, but I looked everywhere for it and didn't find it!! Any help would be tremendously appreciated.
Thanks!
Tao B.

Answer (score 0):

you could grap the link from the minicart which displays the products in the cart and has a text link called "show cart" which links to the items in the cart. This is from the minicart module so if you don't have it installed you won't know what I'm talking about. Publish the module, right click on "show cart" grab the code and you'll be able to manually insert it. Review this file:  / administrator/components/com_virtuemart/html/shop.basket_short.php